# An urn contains $nr$ balls numbered $1,2..,n$

Tags: probability

An urn contains $nr$ balls numbered $1,2..,n$ in such a way that $r$ balls bear the same number $i$ for each $i=1,2,...n$. N balls are drawn at random without replacement. Find the probability that each of the $n$ numbers will appear at least once.

My approach differs from the book so I would appreciate some help understanding what's wrong with it.

We can draw $N$ balls in $nr \choose N$ ways.

We can draw each number at least once as follows: for every number $i=1,2,..,n$ we have $r$ possible balls to choose from. As we have $n$ numbers, we have $r^n$ possible ways of choosing  all the $n$ numbers once.

Now we need to draw $N-n$ balls from the remaining $nr -n$ balls. That's ${nr -n} \choose {N-n}$ different ways.

Putting everything together we have: ${r^n{{nr -n} \choose {N-n}}}\over{nr \choose N}$

Comment: Look for example at the $r$ balls with number $3$. Let A and B be two of them. You have counted as different the situations where A is selected "first", and B is selected later. and the one in which B is selected first, and A later. There are various types of multiple counting involved, so there is no easy adjustment to make the idea work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which book are you using?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see it now. Thank you.

Comment: @Frentos Exercises in Probability [Cacoullos]

Comment: @jjjx: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_1$ be the r.v. for the number of balls numbered $1$ in the sample.
Similarly, define $X_2,\dots,X_n$.
Now, the required probability is $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n[X_i\ge 1])$.
We see it is easier to compute the probability of complement of this event, i.e. $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n[X_i=0])$..(How? Use De Morgan's Law).

So, we calculate the above probability using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle,
$$P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n[X_i=0]) = \sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}{n\choose i}P[X_1=0,\dots,X_i=0]$$
Since, $P[X_1=0]=P[X_2=0] = \frac{{nr-r\choose N}}{{nr\choose N}}$, we use the $\sum_{i=1}^n P[X_i=0] = nP[X_1=0]$ in the above formula and similarly for the other terms.
Now the required probability becomes,
$$P(\bigcap_{i=1}^n[X_i\ge 1]) = 1-P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n[X_i=0]) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n\choose k}\frac{{(n-k)r\choose N}}{{nr\choose N}}$$